# Can you access `client` within a client resolver in ApolloClient, rather than `cache`?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Is it possible to access `client` from within an ApolloClient resolver, rather than `cache`?

I’m trying to write a resolver which clears localStorage and the cache when a button is clicked (essentially a logout), but don’t know how to access the client.

I can access the cache no problem at all, but despite the official docs, I'm getting a `cache.resetStore()` is not a function error in the console (or `cache.clearStore() if I use that function`).

Running ApolloClient, React and apollo-link-state, wrapping components in the `graphql()` HOC with compose.

resolvers.js

```
  Mutation: {
    logout: (_, __, { cache }) => {
      localStorage.clear();
      cache.writeData({
        data: {
          AuthData: {
            __typename: 'AuthData',
            token: null,
            currentUserId: null,
            expirationTime: null
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

//Apollo
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

...
...

const initialState = {
  AuthData: {
    __typename: 'AuthData',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
    currentUserId: localStorage.getItem('currentUserId') || null,
    expirationTime: localStorage.getItem('expirationTime') || null
  },
  ErrorLog: {
    __typename: 'ErrorLog',
    errors: []
  }
};

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  defaults: initialState,
  resolvers
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([stateLink, httpLink]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});
```

Expected:

- Client cache to be cleared of all data.

Actual:

- Getting the error `client is not defined` or `cache.resetStore()` is not a function.